# Выборка из DAO возвращает exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Постоянно выкидывает исключение. При дебаге `subscriptionModels` показывает равным `null`. В базе все нужные значения есть. В чем может быть ошибка ?

```
public void sendCommentNotiffication(String comment, int issueId) {
    try {
        List < SubscriptionModel > subscriptionModels = subscriptionDao.findByIssueId(issueId);
        for (SubscriptionModel subscriptionModel: subscriptionModels) {
            if (subscriptionModel.getId() == 1) {

                String email = userService.getEmailByUserId(subscriptionModel.getUserId());
                String messagePattern = "messagePattern";
                simpleEmailSender(email, "Name", comment, messagePattern);

            } else {
                System.out.println("## Not found");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Something wrong");
    }
}
```

DAO

```
public interface SubscriptionDao extends JpaRepository <SubscriptionModel, Integer>  {

    List<SubscriptionModel> findByIssueId(int issueId);

    SubscriptionModel findByIssueIdAndUserId(int issueId, int userId);

    Collection <SubscriptionModel> findByIssueIdAndIsValid(int issueId, int isValid);
}
```

SubscriptionModel

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTIONS", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"ISSUEID","USERID","ISVALID"}))
public class SubscriptionModel {

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SubscriptionModel.class);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique=true, name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ISSUEID")
    private int issueId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "ISVALID")
    private int isValid;

    public SubscriptionModel() {}


    public SubscriptionModel(int issueId, String email, int userId, int isValid) {
        this.issueId = issueId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }

    public SubscriptionModel(int issueId, int userId) {
        this.issueId = issueId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public SubscriptionModel(int id,int issueId, int userId) {
        this.issueId = issueId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getIssueId() {
        return issueId;
    }

    public void setIssueId(int issueId) {
        this.issueId = issueId;
    }

    public int getIsValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setIsValid(int isValid) {
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        SubscriptionModel that = (SubscriptionModel) o;
        return Objects.equal(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equal(issueId, that.issueId) &&
                Objects.equal(userId, that.userId) &&
                Objects.equal(isValid, that.isValid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id, issueId, userId, isValid);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("id", id)
                .add("issueId", issueId)
                .add("userId", userId)
                .add("isValid", isValid)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Фрагмент Стека без трай /кетч  https://github.com/Oleiva/JS_test/issues/3

Comment: Добавьте контекста немного... Вы какую-то либу для доступа к БД используете? И добавьте код для subscriptionDao - как и почему там мог null возникнуть

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Hibernate, JpaRepository. Код добавил в шапку

Comment: Кажется мне, что не хватает в вопросе реализации `findByIssueId()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Там только интерфейсы. Предполагаеться, что мы наследуем реализацию из  JpaRepository <SubscriptionModel, Integer>  Синтаксис транслируеться в SQL запрос.

Comment: Ну, я в этой технологии ничего не смыслю, так что единственное, что могу предположить - имена переменных в коде не совпадают с именами полей в БД и оттого конфликт. Может с утра кто набежит более сведующий в сих вопросах)

Comment: Ах да, ещё в вопрос добавьте строку, на коей ошибку кидает и stackTrace оной.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо. Добавил

Comment: Для `SubscriptionDao` должен быть какой-то класс, который `implemets SubscriptionDao`. Вот у автора этого класса и спрашивайте в чём дело.

Comment: @banme :)) это спринг автор имплементации.

Comment: а вы пробовали включать трейс запросов гибера? он там вообще к базе-то обращается когда вы этот метод дергаете?

Comment: Попробуйте гвоздями прибить для начала, повесив аннотацию 
`@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE ISSUEID = ?0", nativeQuery = true)` если поможет, то проблема скорее всего в том, что метод должен был называться не findByIssueId а findByIssueid , ибо ваш метод он пытается парсить как issue_id какой-нибудь.. не знаю :) там [магия](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: @banme Трейс в верху  https://github.com/Oleiva/JS_test/issues/3

Comment: @DmitryV. я ещё могу поверить, что `JpaRepository` - это spring. А `SubscriptionDao` и тем более его реализация - это уже чья-то  разработка, опирающаяся на spring. Хотя, что называть spring-ом? С тех времен оброс он множеством сопутствующих прожектов и все они spring чего-то-там. Может среди них и есть spring subscription. Но гуголь не знает такой связки слов. Подозрительно.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at edu.com.softserveinc.bawl.services.impl.MandrillMailServiceImpl.sendCommentNotiffication(MandrillMailServiceImpl.java:159)  
Какая строчка в Ваших блоках кода 159? если эта `for (SubscriptionModel subscriptionModel: subscriptionModels) {` - то всё верно. Так и должно быть, ведь сами говорите `subscriptionModels` равно `null`

Comment: @banme вы что-то странное говорите. Это spring-data, его jpa'шная часть. Почитайте документацию! Достаточно просто сделать интерфейс наследник jpareposiotry а спринг сделает для него прокси которая по заданым правилам (в документации все написано) будет лазить в персист и мапить сущности

Comment: @DmitryV. ссылку на javadoc по SubscriptionDAO из пакетов spring data пожалуйста

Comment: @banme почитайте документацию, пожалуйста!

Comment: @DmitryV. Да читал уже. Думаю, такое запомнил бы. А если нет, то ссылочку, ну пожалуйста:)

Comment: @banme я ведь привел выше, автору, под словом "магия".. сейчас повторю еще раз: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation  вот тут описан процесс создания запроса из имени метода :)

Comment: надо сказать что я прекрасно понимаю Ваше недоумение, @banme. Но это есть, люди накодили :)

Comment: @DmitryV. Там даже среди примеров не встречается слово SubscriptioDao. Люди накодили, но это люди не из spring

Comment: @banme без разницы какое это Dao. имплементацию к нему делает в рантайме спринг, разбирая имена методов на токены и названия полей целевой сущности

Comment: @DmitryV. Так-то тогда понятно. Пусть будет spring

Comment: @bande Да. Но null от там по факту, а не потому, что я ему что то присвоил. В базе все данные есть.

Comment: @Ivasoft а по делу, помогло вам что-нибудь из моих советов?

Comment: @DmitryV. Не особо. Я все еще понятия не имею, почему там null. Если на первый вид все правильно, и я не налажал в DAO, то подозрения падают на аннотацию Autowired на которую неделю назад матерился сборщик.

Comment: а, ну покажите весь код, где там у вас этот autowired  и как вы получили экземпляр объекта этого Dao